# How to replace the Div text with each each occurance of array element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

Array contains following elements
1. abc
2. def
3. ghi

div text

```
this is abc - def some text
```

I want to repalce each occurance with `<p> abc</p>` like that
So final string will be like below.

```
this is <p>abc</p> - <p>def</p> some text
```

I have an Array emements. I have to some text in div. I want to replace each ocurance of arrary element with div text using regex without loop. 
I did it like below using two approiaches

**Approaach #1 using Grep**

```
jQuery.grep(Words, function (val) {
    if (val != null && val != '') {
        Str = Str.replace(val, "<span class='abc'>" + val + "</span>");
    }
});
```

**Approach #2 Using Loop.**

```
$.each(Words, function (keyIndex, val) {
    if (val != null && val != '')
         Str = Str.replace(val, "<span class='abc'>" + val + "</span>");
});
```

Comment: and the question is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
var string = 'this is abc - def some text ';
var array = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];

var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + array.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b', 'g');

var as =string.replace(regex, function(a, b){
    return '<p>'+a+'</p';
});
console.log(as)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/68Jrc/)

Comment: Please explain `var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + array.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b', 'g');` ...

Comment: we are creating a regex with the array components, in this case a regex `/\babc\b|\bdef\b|\bghi\b/g` is created. where any occurrence ex `abc` separated by a space or other word characters wil be matched

Comment: in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/68Jrc/1/) example both the occurrences of `abc` is replaced but `abcd` is not replaced

Comment: But why abcd is not being replaced with <p>abc</p>d

Comment: do you want abcd to be replaced

Comment: do you want abc in abcd to be replaced

Comment: Use the regex `var regex = new RegExp(array.join('|'), 'g');` if you want all occurrences of `abc` replaced as in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/68Jrc/3/)

Comment: How can I remove case sensitivity ?

Comment: use `var regex = new RegExp(array.join('|'), 'gi');`